# Passing query as variable to Rmarkdown sql chunk

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to use the [SQL chunk function](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_knitr_engines.html) available in the [preview version of RStudio 1.0](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/) to connect to a SQL Server (using the RSQLServer backend for DBI) and I'm having some difficulty passing variables.

If I connect to the server and then put the query in the chunk it works as expected

````
```{r, eval = F}
svr <- dbConnect(RSQLServer::SQLServer(), "Server_name", database = 'Database_name')
query <- 'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Database_name.dbo.table_name'
```
```{sql, connection = svr, eval = F}
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Database_name.dbo.table_name
```
````

But if I try to pass the query as a variable it throws an error

````
```{sql, connection = svr, eval = F}
?query
```

Error: Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for 'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Database_name.dbo.table_name': Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Database_name.dbo.table_name'.
Failed to execute SQL chunk
````

I think it's related to the way R wraps character vectors in quotes, because I get the same error if I run the following code.

````
```{sql, connection = svr, eval = F}
'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Database_name.dbo.table_name'
```
````

Is there a way I can get around this error?

Currently I can achieve what I want by [using inline expressions to print the query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39630279/passing-query-as-variable-to-rmarkdown-sql-chunk), [using the pygments for highlighting](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1087) and running the query in a R chunk with DBI commands, so using code chunks would be a bit nicer.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like [Using R variables in queries](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_knitr_engines.html#using-r-variables-in-queries) applies some kind of escaping and can therefore only be used in cases like the example from the documentation (`SELECT * FROM trials WHERE subjects >= ?subjects`) but not to dynamically set up the whole query.

Instead, the [`code` chunk option](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/#chunk_options) can be used to achieve the desired behavior:

<sub>The example uses the [SQLite sample database](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/download/sqlite-sample-database/?wpdmdl=94) from [sqlitetutorial.net](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/). Unzip it to your working directory before running the code.</sub>

````
```{r}
library(DBI)
db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = "chinook.db")
query <- "SELECT * FROM tracks"
```


```{sql, connection=db, code = query}
```
````

Comment: This prints the output with highlighting in a more convenient way than I described in my question. However it looks like it isn't being run.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to determine a way to print and execute in the same chunk however with a few extra lines of code it is possible to achieve my desired output.

Printing is solved by [CL.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39653970/868622) and then I can use [EXEC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms188332.aspx) to run the code.

````
```{sql, code = query}
```

```{sql, connection = svr}
EXEC (?query)
```
````